# Битмап выходит за рамки окна

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть картинка загруженная с помощью gdi+, но при отображении она выходит за рамки окна. Есть ли способ масштабировать `HBITMAP`

вот код отображения:

```
void UI::DrawDef(DRAWITEMSTRUCT* dc)
{
    
        HBITMAP backBitmap = NULL;
        BYTE r = GetRValue(this->defBack),
            g = GetGValue(this->defBack),
            b = GetBValue(this->defBack);

        this->backImage->GetHBITMAP(Gdiplus::Color(r, g, b), &backBitmap);
        HDC nDC = CreateCompatibleDC(dc->hDC);
        HBITMAP old = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(nDC, backBitmap);


        BitBlt(dc->hDC, 0, 0, dc->rcItem.right, dc->rcItem.bottom, nDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(nDC, old);
        DeleteDC(nDC);
        DeleteObject(old);
        DeleteObject(backBitmap);
}
```

Вот собственно результат:
[image]

Comment: StretchBlt.....

Comment: @MBo спасибо, сейчас проверю поможет ли

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо **@MBo**, благодаря его комментарию вопрос решился.
Нужно было вместо `BitBlt` использовать `StretchBlt`